# Significance testing for a group of samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

For instance, I have a bar chart - in which I have 4 samples/bars. for these 4 bars, I want to check statistical significance for all combinations.

1. How can I do it? Can unpaired t-test be used - to compare 2 samples at a time? or this is not correct. What is then the appropriate way in which all the samples/ bars can be compared against each other at the same time.
2. Is there any easy-quick way to nicely represent it in a chart?

thanks

Comment: You may have to correct for multiple testing in this context. You can find more information about that here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons

Comment: thanks for a quick response. the link was helpful, although I am still a bit confused - more so, because I am not too much into statistics.